# how show what program has been run the most times since the system was last rebooted in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process, debian

As it is illustrated in the title, how can i show the program that has been run the most times even its closed, I,m used like below, but it show thr running program just

```
lastreboot | ps -aux --sort=-time | head -2
```

Comment: What is "lastreboot" command? Is it an actual command from some Debian package?

Comment: no, i made a mistake here.. the command ps is right for show process history?

Answer (score 1):

- Most distributions do not record process launch history by default. The [linux auditing framework](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/chap-system_auditing.html) can provide that functionality (among others).
- If you just want to watch launching of children of a certain process for a short amount of time, you could also use `strace` and filter the respective `fork()`/ `exec()` system calls.